# Pseudo-terminal will not allocated because stdin is not a terminal & mess: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: macos, shell, ubuntu, oh-my-zsh

I've written a shell script to scp, ssh, delete a directory, unzip, and remove the zip file

```
#!/bin/bash

tar -czf zipfile.tar.gz ./* .??*
scp zipfile.tar.gz root@some.ip.address:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes
rm zipfile.tar.gz

ssh root@some.ip.address << 'ENDSSH'
cd /some/directory
rm -rf zipfile
mkdir zipfile
tar xf zipfile.tar.gz -C zipfile
rm zipfile.tar.gz
ENDSSH
```

I am noticing that the files are successfully transferred and unzipped.  The zip file is also successfully removed from the server.
However, I notice that I'm receiving these messages in the terminal

```sh
zipfile.tar.gz  100% 224KB ...
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
...
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS...
...

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Running the script before the second block (ENDSSH) seems to not output those messages and executes successfully.

Is the `ENDSSH` causing the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u can write like this:

```
ssh -tt root@some.ip.address << ENDSSH
your code
exit
ENDSSH
```

u try it.